# How do I programmatically generate a dataset in a SSRS report?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I want to execute a SQL query and use the results of that query to generate my own dataset for use in a SSRS report.

More specifically, I'm trying to create a SSRS report subscription calendar. The calendar will display when certain subscriptions are scheduled to run.

I plan to do this by querying the report server's schedule table and generating a row for each scheduled run.

e.g. Subscription A runs every weekday at 2pm. Subscription B runs every Monday at 9am.

This is the dataset I want to generate for some arbitrary week:

```
Monday Sep 14, 9:00:00, Subscription B
Monday Sep 14, 14:00:00, Subscription A
Tuesday Sep 15, 14:00:00, Subscription A
Wednesday Sep 16, 14:00:00, Subscription A
Thursday Sep 17, 14:00:00, Subscription A
Friday Sep 18, 14:00:00, Subscription A
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is the following article useful regarding querying the report server the reports are hosted on/in

[Query SSRS Report Schedules](http://thinknook.com/query-ssrs-report-schedules-2011-06-26/)